# Count unique events in SQL where multiple observations exist for the same person

Tags: sql, count, unique

I have a dataset that contains the name of a researcher and the status of their annual report. There are 3 unique events that can occur

- Event 1: University Reminder Sent -> Response Received
- Event 2: University Reminder Sent -> Library Reminder Sent/Waiting on Response -> Response Received
- Event 3: University Reminder Sent -> Library Reminder Sent/Waiting on Response -> No Response

I have to find the count of how many times each of these events occurred. The problem I am having is that there are multiple observations with the same researcher name.

```
John Doe | University Reminder Sent
John Doe | Library Reminder Sent/Waiting on Response
John Doe | No Response
```

I have tried code such as

```
select name, status 
where status = 'University Reminder Sent"
and status = 'Library Reminder Sent/Waiting on Response"
and status = 'No Response'
```

but this does not work because it is looking for a single observation that has all three statuses. How can I properly count these events?

Comment: one query for each distinct event can work

Comment: @RyanBushman . . . You need to provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are doing -- along with an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `group by`:

```
select status, count(*)
from t
group by status;
```

Comment: So that gives me counts of each status, but I am interested in counting combinations of status. For example, those who responded after receiving a university or library reminder are mutually exclusive from those who did not respond to the reminders. I am interested in counting how many researchers responded or didn't respond at certain points of the process